# Master pages through design manager, how to manage different sharePoint controls on different places in the master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, design-manager

In SharePoint 2013, Client has a requirement to place different SharePoint controls on different places in the master page. How to control this situation when through design manager we can manage how to place different SharePoint controls on different places in the master page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, you have the flexibility to use HTML file to edit the master page and it will be converted to .master file automatically.

That means you can edit the .html version of master page in any Editor (Text editor or Html editor like Notepad++, Dreamweaver, Visual Studio etc.). During editing you can place different SharePoint controls on different location and upload this .html file in SharePoint master page library with correct content type. From design manager you can convert your .html version of master page to .master file and check preview. On preview you have the option to move to `Snippet Gallery`, this gallery allows you to generate SharePoint controls to place in .html version.

Comment: can you put SharePoint controls in dream weaver or notepad++? I don't think so.

Comment: Snippet Gallery will give you code snippets for SharePoint controls that you can use in dreamweaver or notepad++ (in fact any editor). This is new feature in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, You need to build custom master pages using visual studio 2013. deploy the wsp to server.

Comment: Great that you know this. Could you elaborate on the answer explaining in further detail how this should be done? It will be more helpful if you do. Thank you!